# "Call to undefined function getOption()"

Tags: php, laravel

I am using from a layouts file of my old Laravel project in new project.
But When I put the layouts/app.php codes, appeared this error:

> "Call to undefined function getOption()"

The layouts/app.php file codes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="wibdth=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    {!! getOption('home_page_meta') !!}

    <title>@yield('title')</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ asset(getOption('logo')) }}">
    <link href="/css/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css?v={{ config('constants.VERSION') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/css/vendor/datatable/datatables.min.css?v={{ config('constants.VERSION') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    @if(in_array(getOption('language'),$rtlLang))
        <style>
            .table > thead > tr > th, .table > tbody > tr > th, .table > tfoot > tr > th, .table > thead > tr > td, .table > tbody > tr > td, .table > tfoot > tr > td {
                text-align:right; direction:rtl;
            }
        </style>
    @endif
    @if(getOption('panel_theme') == 'material')
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="/css/flat-ui.min.css?v={{ config('constants.VERSION') }}" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="/css/indusrabbit.css?v={{ config('constants.VERSION') }}" rel="stylesheet">
        <style>
            body {
                background-color: {{ getOption('background_color') }} !important;
            }

            .navbar-default {
                background-color: {{ getOption('theme_color') }};
            }

            .btn-primary,
            .btn-primary:hover,
            .btn-primary:active,
            .btn-primary:focus {
                background-color: {{ getOption('theme_color') }};
                border-color: #000;
            }

            .login-form .login-field:focus {
                border-color: {{ getOption('theme_color') }}; 

            }

            a,
            a:active,
            a:focus,
            a:hover {
                color: {{ getOption('theme_color') }};
            }

            .login-link:hover {
                color: {{ getOption('theme_color') }};
            }

            input[type=text]:focus,
            .form-control:focus {
                border-color: {{ getOption('theme_color') }};
            }

            .pagination li.active > a, .pagination li.active > span, .pagination li.active > a:hover, .pagination li.active > span:hover, .pagination li.active > a:focus, .pagination li.active > span:focus {
                background-color: {{ getOption('theme_color') }};
            }

            #footer-menu li a {
                color: {{ getOption('theme_color') }};
                font-size: 14px;
            }

            .pagination li > a:hover, .pagination li > span:hover {
                background-color: {{ getOption('theme_color') }};
            }

            .dropdown-lang li a{
                padding-top: 3px;
                padding-bottom: 3px;
            }

            .theme-bg{
                background-color: {{ getOption('theme_color') }} !important;
            }
        </style>
    @elseif(getOption('panel_theme') == 'simple')
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,400italic" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="/css/indusrabbit-theme-simple.css?v={{ config('constants.VERSION') }}" rel="stylesheet">
        <style>
            .theme-bg{
                background-color: #b9b6b6 !important;
            }
        </style>
    @elseif(getOption('panel_theme') == 'fancy')
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,400italic" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="/css/indusrabbit-theme-fancy.css?v={{ config('constants.VERSION') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    @endif
    <link href="/css/my-style.css?v={{ config('constants.VERSION') }}" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Scripts -->
    <script>
        window.Laravel = <?php echo json_encode([
            'csrfToken' => csrf_token(),
        ]); ?>;
        window.baseUrl = "<?php echo url('/') ?>";
        var spinner = "<span class='loader'></span>";
    </script>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Flat UI's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="/js/vendor/jquery.min.js?v={{ config('constants.VERSION') }}"></script>
    <script src="/js/vendor/form-validator/jquery.form-validator.min.js?v={{ config('constants.VERSION') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });
            $.validate({
                modules: 'date',
                validateOnBlur: false,
                lang: '{{ getOption('language') }}'
            });

            $(document).on('click','.dropdown-lang a',function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var locale = $(this).data('locale');
                $('#locale').val(locale);
                document.getElementById('lang-form').submit();
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script src="/js/my-script.js?v={{ config('constants.VERSION') }}"></script>
</head>
<body dir="{{ $dir }}">
<div id="app">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid" dir="rtl">
            <div class="navbar-header">

                <!-- Collapsed Hamburger -->
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#app-navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

                <!-- Branding Image -->
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="app-navbar-collapse">
                <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    @if (Auth::check())
                        <li>
                            <a href="{{ url('/dashboard') }}">@lang('menus.dashboard')</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="{{ url('/order/new') }}">@lang('menus.new_order')</a>
                        </li>

                        <!--- For disable mass-order page>
                        <li>
                            <a href="{{ url('/order/mass-order') }}">@lang('menus.mass_order')</a>
                        </li> --->

                        <li>
                            <a href="{{ url('/orders') }}">@lang('menus.order_history')</a>
                        <li>
                        @if(getOption('module_subscription_enabled') == 1)
                            <li><a href="{{ url('/subscriptions') }}">@lang('menus.subscriptions')</a></li>
                        @endif
                        <li><a href="{{ url('/services') }}">@lang('menus.service_list')</a></li>

                        <li>
                            <a href="{{ url('/payment/') }}">@lang('menus.add_funds')</a>

                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="{{ url('/support') }}">@lang('menus.support') 
                            </a> 
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="{{ url('/account/settings') }}">@lang('menus.settings')</a>
                        </li>
                        @if(getOption('module_api_enabled') == 1)
                           <li><a href="{{ url('/api') }}">@lang('menus.api')</a></li>
                        @endif
                        <!---
                        <li>
                            <a href="{{ url('/account/funds-load-history') }}">@lang('menus.funds_load_history')</a>
                        </li>
                        --->

                        <li>
                            <a href="{{ url('/logout') }}"
                                onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">@lang('menus.logout')
                            </a>

                            <form id="logout-form" action="{{ url('/logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                {{ csrf_field() }}
                            </form>
                        </li>
                        @else
                        <li><a href="{{ url('/login') }}">@lang('menus.login')</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{{ url('/register') }}">@lang('menus.register')</a></li>
                    @endif
                </ul>

                <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                    <!-- Authentication Links -->
                    @if (Auth::guest())
                        <li><a href="{{ url('/services') }}">@lang('menus.service_list')</a></li>    
                    @else 
                        <li>
                            <a href="{{ url('/payment/zarinpal') }}" style="font-size: 18px;">
                                <span class="label label-success user-fund-top"> Balance:
                                        {{ number_format(Auth::user()->funds,0, getOption('currency_separator'), '')." ". getOption('') }} @lang('curr.code')
                                </span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    @endif
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="clearfix" style="height: 70px;"></div>
    <div class="{{ getOption('user_layout') }}">
        @if(Session::has('alert'))
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-8">
                    <div style="font-size: 15px; margin-top: -15px;" class="alert alert-{{ Session::get('alertClass') }}">
                        <button type="button"
                                class="close"
                                data-dismiss="alert"
                                aria-hidden="true">×
                        </button>
                        {{ Session::get('alert') }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        @endif
        @yield('content')
    </div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="footer">
    <ul id="footer-menu" >
        <li style="text-align:center">Laravel</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<!-- Scripts -->
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="/js/vendor/datatable/datatables.min.js?v={{ config('constants.VERSION') }}"></script>
<script src="/js/flat-ui.min.js?v={{ config('constants.VERSION') }}"></script>
<script src="/js/application.js?v={{ config('constants.VERSION') }}"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {

        if (!$(".alert").hasClass('no-auto-close')) {
            $(".alert").delay(3000).slideUp(300);
        }

    });
</script>
@stack('scripts')
</body>
</html>
```

I'm using a database that resembles the database I used in my previous project
So there are all the instances that existed in the previous database (like them_color) in the new database

The functions.php codes:

```
<?php
if (!function_exists('getOption')):
    function getOption($option, $fetchFromDb = false)
    {
        // If forced to fetch from db
        if ($fetchFromDb) {
            $row = \DB::table('configs')->select('value')->where('name', $option)->first();

            if (is_null($row)) {
                return null;
            } else {
                return $row->value;
            }
        }

        // If session is set then get config option from session
        // otherwise get from database directly
        $options = \Session::get('options');
        if (!is_null($options)) {
            if (array_key_exists($option, $options)) {
                return $options[$option];
            }
            return null;
        }

        // Check if app is installed?
        if (config('database.installed') !== '%installed%') {
            $row = \DB::table('configs')->select('value')->where('name', $option)->first();

            if (is_null($row)) {
                return null;
            } else {
                return $row->value;
            }
        }
        return null;

    }
endif;

if (!function_exists('setOption')):
    function setOption($name, $value)
    {
        $row = \DB::table('configs')->select('value')->where('name', $name)->first();
        if (is_null($row)) {
            \DB::table('configs')->insert(['name' => $name, 'value' => $value]);
        } else {
            \DB::table('configs')->where('name', $name)->update(['value' => $value]);
        }
    }
endif;

if (!function_exists('mpc_m_c')):
    function mpc_m_c($data)
    {
        if(!password_verify($data,getOption('app_key',true)) && !password_verify(strrev($data),getOption('app_code',true))){
            \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::call('down');
        }
    }
endif;

if (!function_exists('array_diff_key_recursive')):
    function array_diff_key_recursive($a1, $a2)
    {
        $r = array();

        foreach ($a1 as $k => $v) {
            if (is_array($v)) {
                if (!isset($a2[$k]) || !is_array($a2[$k])) {
                    $r[$k] = $a1[$k];
                } else {
                    if ($diff = array_diff_key_recursive($a1[$k], $a2[$k])) {
                        $r[$k] = $diff;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (!isset($a2[$k]) || is_array($a2[$k])) {
                    $r[$k] = $v;
                }
            }
        }

        return $r;
    }
endif;

if (!function_exists('array_cast_recursive')):
    function array_cast_recursive($array)
    {
        if (is_array($array)) {
            foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
                if (is_array($value)) {
                    $array[$key] = array_cast_Recursive($value);
                }
                if ($value instanceof stdClass) {
                    $array[$key] = array_cast_Recursive((array)$value);
                }
            }
        }
        if ($array instanceof stdClass) {
            return array_cast_Recursive((array)$array);
        }
        return $array;
    }
endif;

if (!function_exists('getPageContent')):
    function getPageContent($slug)
    {
        return App\Page::where(['slug' => $slug])->first()->content;
    }
endif;
```

composer.json codes:

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"type": "project",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": [
    "framework",
    "laravel"
],
"license": "MIT",
"require": {
    "php": "^7.1.3",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
    "laravel/framework": "5.7.*",
    "laravel/tinker": "^1.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.0",
    "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^2.0",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.0"
},
"config": {
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true,
    "cache-dir": "/home/grammer/public_html/reset/cache"
},
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "dont-discover": []
    }
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ]
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true,
"scripts": {
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
        "@/usr/local/bin/php artisan package:discover --ansi"
    ],
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "@/usr/local/bin/php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "@/usr/local/bin/php artisan key:generate --ansi"
    ]
}
```

}

Comment: why you are using getOption?

Comment: To use the configs table in the database

Comment: Like "home_page_meta" or "them_color"

Comment: you are missing `getOption()` function this must be in some your other files such as index.php or some other files.

Comment: Where I can find it? in controllers? or resources files?

Comment: do a search in whole code base

Comment: I found it
In the Helpers / functions in the old project

But when I add this code to Helpers / functions in my new project, it will not change again

Comment: Can you show the function here? There might be some other way you are missing, maybe that helper not loading or so. Just show the code, I will suggest some other way to work around.

Comment: In fact, the new project did't have the functions.php, I created it and then I copied the codes from the old project. I edited my question and pasted the functions.php codes.

Comment: @Amirhossein I am not asking functions.php. I was asking `getOption()` function. You can try copying `function getOption()` to index.php this should remove error getOption not found error. However, it may produce another as it looks like it is loading some data from the database. So, to run that you might need to import some other files too. Or, you can take a look at the older project. How that helper file is loading.

Comment: So you are saying I should copy `function getOption()`  in  layouts/app.blade.php . yes?

Comment: It's a simple issue your functions.php isn't getting loaded just mark for autoloading.Post your composer.json if this is unclear.

Comment: I added the composer.Jason codes in my question